# Maximum number of parameters in a Agent-Type

Tags: anylogic

Good morning everyone,
I am working on a very large simulation model. The agent that moves within all the flow-charts is always the same Agent-Type, and I have exceeded the maximum number of parameters an agent can contain(255). Creating another Agent-Type doesn't allow me to be able to pass that agent through all the flow-chartsI've already developed. Is there another way to go about this?

TNX

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to follow Java best practices and have a Java class (which has almost no limitations) and save all your variables in there. Then you simply pass an instance of the Java class to the agent. This really simplifies things as your agent will only have 1 parameter.

You can see more detail about how this is done in this blog post - https://www.theanylogicmodeler.com/post/the-simulation-model-life-cycle-part-2-working-the-data

See the section about using a data object, and you can also download the example model which uses this methodology

Comment: Hi Jaco-Ben, if the class is used to store all parameters, let us assume you now have 2 classes with 255 each. Would it be possible to run an optimization experiment for these 255*2=510 parameters?

Comment: @MajedHadid Don't hijack another question with a tangential one as a comment on an answer. You already have your SO question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73914372